# how to use custom function for uploading files in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I made a custom function before working with framework, that I want to use again now. the problem occurs when I tried uploading image with my custom function. it says error `undefined index : [the field_name]`.

most people uses CI library and CI upload function `do_upload()` but I want to use my own function because it also creates smaller image to be used as thumb.

I started working with CI 3 days ago, and still don't know how to change anything that can make `$_FILES[]` working.

the view :

```
  <form action="path/to/controller/method" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fupload">

  </form>
```

the controller :

```
   public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('fungsi_thumb'); // this is the custom function
    $config['allowed_types'] = '*';

    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
}

  public function input_file(){


     $data = array(
        'location_file' => $_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name'],
        'type_file' => $_FILES['fupload']['type'],
        'name_file' => $_FILES['fupload']['name']
       );

     $this->load->model('input_model');
     $this->input_model->put_file($data);
  }
```

I already put my custom function file in `application\helpers\`. Should I show the custom function file and the model file too?

I already change the `public $allowed_types = '*';` too

**UPDATE**

the Model

```
   public function put_file($data){
       //BUAT FILE
    $lokasi_file = $data['location_file'];
    $tipe_file = $data['type_file'];
    $nama_file = $data['name_file'];
    $acak = rand(1,99);
    $nama_file_unik = $acak.$nama_file;

    UploadImage($nama_file_unik); // this is my custom function

     $sql="INSERT INTO produk(gambar)VALUES (?)";
    $query=$this->db->query($sql,array($nama_file_unik));
    if($query)
    {
        echo "BERHASIL";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "GAGAL";
    }

   }
```

**UPDATE NEW**
I finally able to use `$_FILES`, I need to load the library **inside** the controller Constructor.

now the new problem is there is no file uploaded even using `do_upload()` function inside my own custom made function

**this is my custom made function**

```
   function UploadImage($fupload_name){

// SET DATA FILE NYA
 $config['file_name'] = $fupload_name;
 $config['upload_path'] = 'http://localhost/mobileapp/assets/gambar/';

var_dump($config['upload_path']);

//load the upload library
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->library('upload',$config);

//Upload the file
  if( !($CI->upload->do_upload('fupload'))){
     $error = $CI->upload->display_errors();
 }else{
     $file_data = $CI->upload->data();
 }
}
```

now as you can see above, I'm trying to change the `file_name` to a new randomly-generated name (done in the model) using `$config['file_name'] = $fupload_name;` and making a new object because obviously I need to do this to load library and use the `do_upload()` method.

but I still cannot use it. now I'm stuck again

Comment: Show us your `put_file` function in `input_model` to get the actual problem.

Comment: the `Upload.php` file from CI also uses `$_FILES[]` but when I use it, it shows `undefined index`.... why?

Comment: edited now @RohanKumar

Answer (score 1):

Pass `$_FILES` array from controller to model function, add new file name in config array and use [do_upload()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#CI_Upload::do_upload) directly like,

**Controller Function:**

```
public function input_file(){
    $this->load->model('input_model');
    $this->input_model->put_file($_FILES); // pass $_FILES Array
}
```

**Model Function:**

```
public function put_file($files){
    $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
    $acak = rand(1,99);
    $config['file_name'] = $acak.$files['fupload']['name'];
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    $data = array(
       'location_file' => $files['fupload']['tmp_name'],
       'type_file' => $files['fupload']['type'],
       'name_file' => $files['fupload']['name']
    );
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('fupload')) { // pass field name here
        $this->upload->display_errors('<p>', '</p>');
    } else {
       $sql="INSERT INTO produk(gambar)VALUES (?)";
       $query=$this->db->query($sql,array($nama_file_unik));
       if($query) {
          echo "BERHASIL";
       } else {
          echo "GAGAL";
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok. but this way, I'll be using `do_upload()` function instead of my own function? never mind, I think I can still use my own function

Comment: sorry. still `undefined index : fupload` I cannot pass the `$_FILES` or something?

Comment: after using `echo var_dump($_FILES);`  I get `array(0) { }` why is it empty? and when I `echo var_dump($_POST);` I get the file name in this array, as string

Comment: It must print array if your have valid action and submitting your form correctly. Check in browser's console for the post parameters and url.

Comment: exactly. I submitted `type="text"` and `type="file"` in one form and use `var_dump($_POST);` and `var_dump($_FILES);` I get array result of `POST` and **empty** array of `FILES` I think the submit action is valid and it is submitting my form correctly

Comment: Confirm that you are selecting a file before form submit.

Comment: how do I do that? `if(isset($_FILES)){ I do not know the code to submit }`

Comment: never mind. turns out I need to load the library class inside the constructor in controller class

Answer (score 1):

***upload_path*** in configs must be absolute or relative path and not an url.
So you can something like this():

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
```

OR this:

```
$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'uploads/';
```

Note: FCPATH is absolute path of your index.php folder.

Comment: isn't url an absolute path though? I will try to use relative path. my `assets/gambar` is located at the same directory with index.php so my relative path should be `../assets/gambar/` or `/assets/gambar` ?

Comment: Use this: `$config['upload_path'] = './assets/gambar/';`